# Removing duplicate elements & count repetitions in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, counting

This is more difficult than I expected. I have a sorted ArrayList of Strings (words), and my task is to remove the repetitions and print out a list of each word, followed by the number of the word's repetitions. Suffice it to say that it's more complex than I expected. After trying different things, I decided to use a HashMap to store the words (key), value(repetitions).

This is the code. Dictionary is the sorted ArrayList and Repetitions that HashMap.

```
public void countElements ()
    {
    String word=dictionary.get(0);
            int wordCount=1;
            int count=dictionary.size();
            for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
                word=dictionary.get(i);

                for (int j=i+1; j<count;j++)
                {


                    if(word.equals(dictionary.get(j)))
                    {

                        wordCount=wordCount+1;
                        repetitions.put(word, wordCount);                           
                        dictionary.remove(j--);                            
                        count--;

                    }


                }
            }
```

For some reason that I do not understand (I'm a beginner), after I call the dictionary.remove(j--) method, variable j decrements by 1, even though it should be i+1. What am I missing? Any ideas on how to do this properly would be appreciated. I know that it would be best to use an iterator, but that can become even more confusing. 
Many thanks.

Comment: It wouldn't be best to use an Iterator.

Comment: You're overthinking it. The list doesn't even have to be sorted. For each word, you check if it's already in the map. If true, you increment the value in the map, otherwise you add it in the map with the value 1. With streams, you can do that in 1 line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will serve your purpose. Now dictionary would contain the unique words and hashmap would contain the frequency count of each word.

```
   public class newq {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> dictionary=new ArrayList<String>();
        dictionary.add("hello");
        dictionary.add("hello");
        dictionary.add("asd");
        dictionary.add("qwet");
        dictionary.add("qwet");
        HashMap<String,Integer> hs=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        int i=0;
        while(i<dictionary.size())
        {
            String word=dictionary.get(i);
            if(hs.containsKey(word))   // check if word repeated
            {
               hs.put(word, hs.get(word)+1); //if repeated increase the count
               dictionary.remove(i); // remove the word

            }
            else
            {
               hs.put(word, 1);  //not repeated
               i++;
            }

       }
       Iterator it = hs.entrySet().iterator();
       while(it.hasNext())
        {
          HashMap.Entry pair = (HashMap.Entry)it.next();
           System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
          it.remove();
        }
        for(String word: dictionary)
        {
           System.out.println(word);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh my. Don't use raw types. And since you know about iterators, why don't you use one for the first loop. It would be so much safer and clearer. Using Map.merge() would be simpler, too.

Comment: Many, many thanks to everyone who responded. You've been very helpful. And yes, as JB Nizet said I have been overthinking it a bit (spent too much time on it.) Bu there is still one last thing I don't understand. Why after my dictionary.remove(j--) method call, the j value is decreased by 1. Since I haven't assigned a new value to the j variable it shouldn't decrease, should it? I checked that using the debugger and print statements. I am definitely missing something.

Answer (score 1):

A version which uses streams:

```
    final Map<String, Long> countMap = dictionary.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(word -> word, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println("Counts follow");
    System.out.println(countMap);
    System.out.println("Duplicate-free list follows");
    System.out.println(countMap.keySet());
```

Here we group (using `Collectors.groupingBy`) the elements of the list using each element (i.e. each word) as a key in the resulting map, and counting this word occurrences (using `Collectors.counting()`).

Outer collector (`groupingBy`) uses `counting` collector as a downstream collector that collects (here, counts) all the occurrences of a single word.

We're using `LinkedHashMap` here to build the map because it maintains the order in which key-value pairs were added to it as we want to maintain the same order that words had in your initial list.

And one more thing: `countMap.keySet()` is not a `List`. If you want to get a `List` in the end, it's just `new ArrayList(countMap.keySet())`.

Comment: It doesn't remove duplicates from the list, though.

Comment: Oops, I've forgot about that. Adjusted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want 'j' to decrement you should use j-1.
Using j--, --j, j++, or ++j changes the value of the variable.

[This link](http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-increment-decrement-operator/) has a good explanation and simple examples about post- en pre-incrementing.

Comment: Many, many thanks. These differences are quite subtle and not easy to find.